# MySQL PHP query based on prior query array results

Tags: php, mysql

Using PHP I am querying a MYSQL database and returning 4 results.  These results represent the ID of 4 rows.

I now want to run another PHP query that will identify a field named Counter for each of the row ID's and increment it by 1.  Seems pretty simple using arrays and a loop, but I'm not sure how to approach this in PHP.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it in one:

```
UPDATE counter SET counter = counter + 1 
WHERE id IN ( ...your...select...query);
```

Or possibly without a subquery, I don't know your starting query or data.

Comment: Most excellent.  Exactly what I needed.  I hadn't thought about using a subquery, I was thinking arrays/loops.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For this you use [update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html)

```
update mytable
set counter = counter + 1
where id = 15
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets say that $ids contains your ids.

```
$ids[] = 0; //to exclude the case when $ids is empty
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET Counter = Counter + 1 WHERE ID IN (" . implode(',', $ids) . ")");
```

Answer (score 2):

It could be done in single query:

```
UPDATE table_name SET Counter = Counter + 1 WHERE id IN (your sub query )
```